# How to create contact point in grafana using API?

Tags: api, grafana, grafana-api

I am trying to create a contact point in grafana for pagerduty using grafana API.

Tried with the help of these URLS: [AlertProvisioning](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/alerting_provisioning/) [HTTP_API](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/)
API call [reference](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/create-api-tokens-for-org/)

YAML reference of data changed to JSON and tried this way, the YAML [reference](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/grafana/values.yaml#L516-L576)

But getting error as

```
{"message":"invalid object specification: type should not be an empty string","traceID":"00000000000000000000000000000000"}
```

My API code below, replaced with dummy integration key for security.

```
curl -X POST --insecure -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "contactPoints": [
    {
      "orgId": 1,
      "name": "test1",
      "receivers": [
        {
          "uid": "test1",
          "type": "pagerduty",
          "settings": {
            "integrationKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "severity": "critical",
            "class": "ping failure",
            "component": "Grafana",
            "group": "app-stack",
            "summary": "{{ `{{ template \"default.message\" . }}` }}"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
  "overwrite": false
}' http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/api/v1/provisioning/contact-points
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to enable [Grafana swagger UI](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/602ee3753321adb47b1768049e8f35ad25508029/docs/sources/whatsnew/whats-new-in-v8-4.md#openapi-v2-specification). You will see `POST /api/v1/provisioning/contact-points` model there:

[image]

Example:

```
{
  "disableResolveMessage": false,
  "name": "webhook_1",
  "settings": {},
  "type": "webhook",
  "uid": "my_external_reference"
}
```

Comment: can you share steps how to deploy that using helm charts. I am new to grafana, sorry if that is a small question

Comment: @Jor-El sorry, helm is not in the scope of your question - you asked how to create contact point via API, so you have an answer how to create via API. Please accept answer if it is correct answer.

Comment: my bad, sorry for that.
But for this, I didn't get your steps exactly, can you please send the steps in detail, or any links

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't know how enable swagger in grafana.
You need add swaggerUi = true in [feature_toggles] section in grafana.ini and restart your service or pod or container
I hope that this information will be useful for somebody